# ionic/cordova plugin not compiled

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

On one of my machines, I have a list of plugins added in my project and correctly added to platforms (ios and android) :

```
$ ionic plugins ls
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp 3.2.2 "Custom URL scheme"
nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing 4.3.15 "SocialSharing"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.3.0 "Notification"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 1.0.0 "Splashscreen"
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.10 "StatusBar"
org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.13 "Vibration"
```

When I build my project, js files of plugins are correctly added to the build, but Objective-C or Java files aren't compiled with, so the plugins cannot work correctly.

For example, on the working machine :

```
$ ionic build ios | grep -i sharing
CompileC [...] -o /Users/obeone/Documents/ze-coloc/mobile/platforms/ios/build/App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/i386/SocialSharing.o
$
```

On non-working, I have no output.

Both machines are Mac OS X Yosemite, using the same freshly clone git repo.
Both are using same versions of ionic (1.3.14) and cordova (4.2.0).

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

The machine on which I had the problem is used for continous integration, so it start everytime with a fresh repo.

After the git clone, I was doing a `ionic platform add ios`, so it download plugins etc. I don't know why, but plugins was not correctly added to the platform.
When after the `ionic platform add ios`, I do a `ionic platform rm ios` and another `ionic platform add ios`, it's ok, the plugins correctly build on the platform…